# Split page template and tapped event

Tags: c#, windows, xaml, windows-8, windows-store-apps

I use windows 8 Item template that displays a grid and I populate it with my data. Each grid item would then take me to specified page. How do I extract which grid item element got tapped so that I can take the user to appropriate page ? That's how I populate data:

```
 private ObservableCollection<MenuItem> MenuItems = new ObservableCollection<MenuItem>();
```

Thats inside onNavigatedTo(). It all works

```
 MenuItems.Add(new MenuItem
        {
            Title = "Tips",
            Subtitle = "Useful information that helps you to become lucid",
            Image = new BitmapImage(new Uri("ms-appx:///Images/tips.png",
            UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute))
        });
        MenuItems.Add(new MenuItem
        {
            Title = "FAQ",
            Subtitle = "Most commonly asked questions",
            Image = new BitmapImage(new Uri("ms-appx:///Images/faq.png",
            UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute))
        });
        itemGridView.ItemsSource = MenuItems;
        itemListView.ItemsSource = MenuItems;
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You populated your data in a GridView and ListView. Those controls have almost the same interactions. In your Xaml page, modify your Gridview to have at least those properties :

```
<GridView x:Name="itemGridView"
  SelectionMode="None"
  IsItemClickEnabled="True"
  ItemClick="ItemView_ItemClick"/>
```

and the ListView :

```
<ListView x:Name="itemListView"
      SelectionMode="None"
      IsItemClickEnabled="True"
      ItemClick="ItemView_ItemClick"/>
```

and add the "ItemView_ItemClick" event to the Xaml.cs to take the user to the appropriate page.

For more infos : [How to change the interaction mode (Windows Store apps using C#/VB/C++ and XAML)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh780625.aspx) on MSDN

Comment: Yes but how do I determine which gridView element got clicked in c# code ? There is many items in my grid and each would navigate to a different page. Thanks

Comment: @Frugo
private void ItemView_ItemClick(object sender, ItemClickEventArgs e)
{
     MenuItem item = (MenuItem)e.ClickedItem;
     //Navigate to the next page with item as parameter
     this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(YourAppropriatePage),item);
}

Comment: that brings me to the same page each time a click whatever item in the grid. How do I code a different page for each grid item clicked ?

Comment: @Frugo
private void ItemView_ItemClick(object sender, ItemClickEventArgs e)
{
     MenuItem item = ( MenuItem )e.ClickedItem;
     switch (MenuItem.Title)
     {
          case "Tips":
               this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(TipsPage));
               break;
          case "FAQ":
               this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(FAQPage));
               break;
     }
}